# Storm Cluster Mode Error

Tags: cluster-computing, runtimeexception, apache-storm

Firstly I am a beginner in Storm and so i want your tolerance for my incomplete report of my question. I have completed the project in local mode and it runs smoothly, without any problems.

I tried to run it in the setup-ed cluster of my university. And i see in the log at cluster's UI that never start running cause of an error. The same error in all the bolts and spouts of my topology. I attach the log with the error of one of a spouts.

I know that my description is inadequate but if you tell my what else is useful to inform you about i will add it to the post.

Thank you

```
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-2--1, built on 03/31/2015 19:31 GMT
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:host.name=clu18.softnet.tuc.gr
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_80
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-plugins-common-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/clj-stacktrace-0.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/oncrpc-1.0.7.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/chill-java-0.3.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-http-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/hadoop-common-2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/tools.cli-0.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/java.classpath-0.2.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-io-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/hadoop-auth-2.4.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/compojure-1.1.3.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-1.3.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-security-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-plugins-impl-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-util-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/clojure-1.5.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ns-tracker-0.2.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/clout-1.0.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-continuation-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-servlets-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-anti-forgery-1.0.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/crypto-equality-1.0.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-server-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/gmetric4j-1.0.7.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/logback-core-1.0.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/carbonite-1.4.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-servlet-1.3.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-plugins-cred-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-storm-plugin-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-servlet-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/kryo-2.21.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-plugins-audit-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/tools.namespace-0.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-configuration-1.10.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/crypto-random-1.2.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-client-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-devel-1.3.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/conf:/usr/hdp/current/storm-supervisor/contrib/storm-jmxetric/lib/jmxetric-1.0.4.jar:/hadoop/storm/supervisor/stormdist/aek-16-1436963685/stormjar.jar:/usr/hdp/current/storm-client/contrib/storm-jmxetric/lib/jmxetric-1.0.4.jar
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.library.path=/hadoop/storm/supervisor/stormdist/aek-16-1436963685/resources/Linux-amd64:/hadoop/storm/supervisor/stormdist/aek-16-1436963685/resources:/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/hdp/current/storm-client/lib
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:os.name=Linux
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:os.version=3.2.0-70-generic
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:user.name=storm
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:user.home=/home/storm
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Client environment:user.dir=/home/storm
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-2--1, built on 03/31/2015 19:31 GMT
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:host.name=clu18.softnet.tuc.gr
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.version=1.7.0_80
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.class.path=/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-plugins-common-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/clj-stacktrace-0.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/oncrpc-1.0.7.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/chill-java-0.3.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-http-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/hadoop-common-2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/tools.cli-0.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/java.classpath-0.2.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-io-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/hadoop-auth-2.4.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/compojure-1.1.3.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-1.3.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-security-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-plugins-impl-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-util-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/clojure-1.5.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ns-tracker-0.2.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/clout-1.0.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-continuation-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-servlets-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-anti-forgery-1.0.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/crypto-equality-1.0.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-server-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/gmetric4j-1.0.7.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/logback-core-1.0.6.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/carbonite-1.4.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-servlet-1.3.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-plugins-cred-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-storm-plugin-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-servlet-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/kryo-2.21.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ranger-plugins-audit-0.4.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/tools.namespace-0.2.4.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-configuration-1.10.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/crypto-random-1.2.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/jetty-client-7.6.13.v20130916.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/ring-devel-1.3.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/conf:/usr/hdp/current/storm-supervisor/contrib/storm-jmxetric/lib/jmxetric-1.0.4.jar:/hadoop/storm/supervisor/stormdist/aek-16-1436963685/stormjar.jar:/usr/hdp/current/storm-client/contrib/storm-jmxetric/lib/jmxetric-1.0.4.jar
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.library.path=/hadoop/storm/supervisor/stormdist/aek-16-1436963685/resources/Linux-amd64:/hadoop/storm/supervisor/stormdist/aek-16-1436963685/resources:/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/hdp/current/storm-client/lib
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:os.name=Linux
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:os.version=3.2.0-70-generic
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:user.name=storm
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:user.home=/home/storm
2015-07-15 15:34:48 o.a.s.z.s.ZooKeeperServer [INFO] Server environment:user.dir=/home/storm
2015-07-15 15:34:49 b.s.d.worker [INFO] Launching worker for aek-16-1436963685 on 3a7d0fdf-91c7-461c-bc24-2c912a622f34:6701 with id 3229d690-cb75-45a3-bab4-e3d0dad1c9a3 and conf {"dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "supervisor.run.worker.as.user" false, "topology.max.error.report.per.interval" 5, "storm.group.mapping.service" "backtype.storm.security.auth.ShellBasedGroupsMapping", "zmq.linger.millis" 5000, "topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations" false, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m ", "storm.zookeeper.session.timeout" 20000, "ui.filter.params" nil, "nimbus.reassign" true, "storm.auth.simple-acl.admins" [], "storm.group.mapping.service.cache.duration.secs" 120, "topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis" 500, "drpc.authorizer.acl.filename" "drpc-auth-acl.yaml", "storm.messaging.netty.flush.check.interval.ms" 10, "ui.header.buffer.bytes" 4096, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m ", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/hdp/current/storm-client/lib", "supervisor.supervisors" [], "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "metrics.reporter.register" "org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsReporter", "storm.local.dir" "/hadoop/storm", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "drpc.authorizer.acl.strict" false, "storm.nimbus.retry.times" 5, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "storm.meta.serialization.delegate" "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultSerializationDelegate", "topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "clu01.softnet.tuc.gr", "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2181, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "ui.http.creds.plugin" "backtype.storm.security.auth.DefaultHttpCredentialsPlugin", "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size" 1024, "logs.users" nil, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "storm.zookeeper.root" "/storm", "storm.zookeeper.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 30000, "supervisor.enable" true, "storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.servers" ["clu02.softnet.tuc.gr" "clu01.softnet.tuc.gr" "clu03.softnet.tuc.gr"], "transactional.zookeeper.root" "/transactional", "topology.acker.executors" nil, "storm.auth.simple-acl.users" [], "storm.zookeeper.auth.user" nil, "topology.testing.always.try.serialize" false, "topology.transfer.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.principal.tolocal" "backtype.storm.security.auth.DefaultPrincipalToLocal", "topology.worker.childopts" nil, "drpc.queue.size" 128, "worker.childopts" "-Xmx768m  -javaagent:/usr/hdp/current/storm-client/contrib/storm-jmxetric/lib/jmxetric-1.0.4.jar=host=localhost,port=8650,wireformat31x=true,mode=multicast,config=/usr/hdp/current/storm-client/contrib/storm-jmxetric/conf/jmxetric-conf.xml,process=Worker_%ID%_JVM", "storm.auth.simple-acl.users.commands" [], "supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 5, "topology.error.throttle.interval.secs" 10, "storm.nimbus.retry.interval.millis" 2000, "ui.users" nil, "zmq.hwm" 0, "drpc.port" 3772, "supervisor.monitor.frequency.secs" 3, "drpc.childopts" "-Xmx768m ", "topology.receiver.buffer.size" 8, "task.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 3, "topology.tasks" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.max_retries" 30, "topology.spout.wait.strategy" "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy", "nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size" 1048576, "drpc.invocations.threads" 64, "drpc.https.port" -1, "supervisor.supervisors.commands" [], "topology.metrics.consumer.register" [{"class" "org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink", "parallelism.hint" 1}], "topology.max.spout.pending" nil, "ui.filter" nil, "logviewer.cleanup.age.mins" 10080, "storm.zookeeper.retry.interval" 1000, "topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms" 1, "nimbus.topology.validator" "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator", "supervisor.slots.ports" [6700 6701], "storm.messaging.netty.authentication" false, "topology.environment" nil, "topology.debug" false, "nimbus.thrift.threads" 64, "nimbus.task.launch.secs" 120, "nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs" 60, "drpc.http.creds.plugin" "backtype.storm.security.auth.DefaultHttpCredentialsPlugin", "topology.message.timeout.secs" 30, "task.refresh.poll.secs" 10, "topology.workers" 1, "supervisor.childopts" "-Xmx256m  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=56431 -javaagent:/usr/hdp/current/storm-supervisor/contrib/storm-jmxetric/lib/jmxetric-1.0.4.jar=host=localhost,port=8650,wireformat31x=true,mode=multicast,config=/usr/hdp/current/storm-supervisor/contrib/storm-jmxetric/conf/jmxetric-conf.xml,process=Supervisor_JVM", "storm.auth.simple-white-list.users" [], "nimbus.thrift.port" 6627, "drpc.https.keystore.type" "JKS", "topology.stats.sample.rate" 0.05, "task.credentials.poll.secs" 30, "worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 1, "ui.actions.enabled" true, "topology.tuple.serializer" "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer", "drpc.https.keystore.password" "", "topology.disruptor.wait.strategy" "com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy", "topology.multilang.serializer" "backtype.storm.multilang.JsonSerializer", "drpc.max_buffer_size" 1048576, "nimbus.task.timeout.secs" 30, "storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout" 15000, "topology.kryo.factory" "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultKryoFactory", "drpc.invocations.port" 3773, "logviewer.port" 8000, "zmq.threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.times" 5, "topology.worker.receiver.thread.count" 1, "storm.thrift.transport" "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin", "topology.state.synchronization.timeout.secs" 60, "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" 30, "nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs" 600, "nimbus.credential.renewers.freq.secs" 600, "storm.messaging.transport" "backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context", "worker.gc.childopts" "", "logviewer.appender.name" "A1", "storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms" 1000, "storm.zookeeper.auth.password" nil, "drpc.http.port" 3774, "drpc.request.timeout.secs" 600, "storm.local.mode.zmq" false, "ui.port" 8745, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m  -javaagent:/usr/hdp/current/storm-nimbus/contrib/storm-jmxetric/lib/jmxetric-1.0.4.jar=host=localhost,port=8649,wireformat31x=true,mode=multicast,config=/usr/hdp/current/storm-nimbus/contrib/storm-jmxetric/conf/jmxetric-conf.xml,process=Nimbus_JVM", "storm.cluster.mode" "distributed", "topology.optimize" true, "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.transfer.batch.size" 262144, "storm.nimbus.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 60000, "topology.classpath" nil, "storm.log.dir" "/var/log/storm"}
2015-07-15 15:34:49 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxSleepTimeMs [30000] the maxRetries [5]
2015-07-15 15:34:49 o.a.s.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl [INFO] Starting
2015-07-15 15:34:49 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Initiating client connection, connectString=clu02.softnet.tuc.gr:2181,clu01.softnet.tuc.gr:2181,clu03.softnet.tuc.gr:2181 sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.curator.ConnectionState@1ce9f29c
2015-07-15 15:34:49 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server clu02.softnet.tuc.gr/147.27.14.202:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-07-15 15:34:49 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to clu02.softnet.tuc.gr/147.27.14.202:2181, initiating session
2015-07-15 15:34:49 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server clu02.softnet.tuc.gr/147.27.14.202:2181, sessionid = 0x24d6c5b265b5e1a, negotiated timeout = 20000
2015-07-15 15:34:49 o.a.s.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2015-07-15 15:34:49 b.s.zookeeper [INFO] Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
2015-07-15 15:34:50 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Session: 0x24d6c5b265b5e1a closed
2015-07-15 15:34:50 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] EventThread shut down
2015-07-15 15:34:50 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxSleepTimeMs [30000] the maxRetries [5]
2015-07-15 15:34:50 o.a.s.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl [INFO] Starting
2015-07-15 15:34:50 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Initiating client connection, connectString=clu02.softnet.tuc.gr:2181,clu01.softnet.tuc.gr:2181,clu03.softnet.tuc.gr:2181/storm sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.curator.ConnectionState@10c3dd25
2015-07-15 15:34:50 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server clu02.softnet.tuc.gr/147.27.14.202:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-07-15 15:34:50 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to clu02.softnet.tuc.gr/147.27.14.202:2181, initiating session
2015-07-15 15:34:50 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server clu02.softnet.tuc.gr/147.27.14.202:2181, sessionid = 0x24d6c5b265b5e1b, negotiated timeout = 20000
2015-07-15 15:34:50 o.a.s.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2015-07-15 15:34:50 b.s.s.a.AuthUtils [INFO] Got AutoCreds []
2015-07-15 15:34:50 b.s.d.worker [INFO] Reading Assignments.
2015-07-15 15:34:50 b.s.m.TransportFactory [INFO] Storm peer transport plugin:backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Loading executor __metricsorg.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink:[2 2]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: __metricsorg.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink __system ["startup"]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Loaded executor tasks __metricsorg.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink:[2 2]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Finished loading executor __metricsorg.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink:[2 2]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Preparing bolt __metricsorg.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink:(2)
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Loading executor distributeeventbolt:[3 3]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: distributeeventbolt __system ["startup"]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Loaded executor tasks distributeeventbolt:[3 3]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate a class listed in config under section topology.metrics.consumer.register with fully qualified name org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink
    at backtype.storm.metric.MetricsConsumerBolt.prepare(MetricsConsumerBolt.java:46) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4641$fn__4654.invoke(executor.clj:732) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__551.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at backtype.storm.metric.MetricsConsumerBolt.prepare(MetricsConsumerBolt.java:44) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [ERROR] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate a class listed in config under section topology.metrics.consumer.register with fully qualified name org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink
    at backtype.storm.metric.MetricsConsumerBolt.prepare(MetricsConsumerBolt.java:46) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4641$fn__4654.invoke(executor.clj:732) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__551.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at backtype.storm.metric.MetricsConsumerBolt.prepare(MetricsConsumerBolt.java:44) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Finished loading executor distributeeventbolt:[3 3]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Preparing bolt distributeeventbolt:(3)
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Prepared bolt distributeeventbolt:(3)
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Loading executor distributeeventbolt:[4 4]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: distributeeventbolt __system ["startup"]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Loaded executor tasks distributeeventbolt:[4 4]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Finished loading executor distributeeventbolt:[4 4]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Preparing bolt distributeeventbolt:(4)
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Prepared bolt distributeeventbolt:(4)
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Loading executor distributeeventbolt:[5 5]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.task [INFO] Emitting: distributeeventbolt __system ["startup"]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Loaded executor tasks distributeeventbolt:[5 5]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Finished loading executor distributeeventbolt:[5 5]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Preparing bolt distributeeventbolt:(5)
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Prepared bolt distributeeventbolt:(5)
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Loading executor eventspout:[6 6]
2015-07-15 15:34:51 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:322) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5053$fn__5054.invoke(worker.clj:495) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__4474$fn__4475.invoke(executor.clj:245) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__551.invoke(util.clj:475) [storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar:0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

EDIT_1:
I made an export of my topology as Runnable Jar via Eclipse but this came along in my terminal.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder$BoltGetter.customGrouping(TopologyBuilder.java:340)
        at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder$BoltGetter.customGrouping(TopologyBuilder.java:264)
        at main.java.storm.Main.main(Main.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar. [jar:file:/home/gdidymiotis/teliko_1.0.0_runnable.jar!/defaults.yaml, jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/storm/lib/storm-core-0.9.3.2.2.4.2-2.jar!/defaults.yaml]
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:139)
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readDefaultConfig(Utils.java:166)
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:190)
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:77)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: Excluding `storm-core.jar` from dependencies during export should resolve the duplicate `defaults.yaml` problem. (or open exported jar and remove manually)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Eclipse have created a packet of maven dependencies with over 40 jars inside. Should i exclude them all? Also i can exclude them during export. Can u describe me the method that u refer to?

Comment: I see. Eclipse seems to be not very helpful with packaging the correct stuff together. If you want to use maven, please refer to the maven manual (it's more complicated as I can explain it here). Or you package manually. I would recommend, that you include only the jar that contains `org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink` what is the initially missing file.

Comment: Just one more comment. If you export via "Java -> JAR" you can also put the missing jar dependencies into Storm's lib directory (on each node in the cluster), ie, into `$STORM_HOME/lib"`.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I have no access on the cluster. So i can not add the missing jar. Does my pom file have wrong dependencies and that creates the whole problem in exporting?

Comment: If you want to use maven to build your project you do no export via Eclipse. Use `maven-jar-plugin` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The log shows the problem clearly: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.storm.StormTimelineMetricsSink`

I guess, this file in not included in the jar you submit to Storm.

Comment: I export my project from eclipse. Right Click(on my project)->Export...->Java->JAR file->Finish(without changing any of configurations). Is that right? I guess not but i dont know any other method? Can u suggest me?

Comment: Export via Eclipse only packages your own class files into the jar. However, you need to include the content of you dependency jars, too. If you export into a `Runnable Jar` you should be able to include those. (I personally use maven.)

Comment: I edit my post because i couldn't comment with so many characters. :P

Comment: @matthias-j-sax Can u guide me (if you can with steps) how to export my project with maven? I work in Windows system Thank you